# Glassfish v2 asadmin "deploy" jar files

Tags: glassfish, asadmin

Is there a way in glassfish v2 asadmin utility to copy jar files into the server lib or the domain's lib? I want to do a remote deployment using hudson on a different box so i have a script that executes a bunch of asadmin commands.

Comment: Can't hudson copy the files to a share or to the server iteself?

Answer (score 0):

asadmin deploy moves your deployable code to the autodeploy directory making glassfish aware of its existence to deploy.  I believe copying a simple library out there won't net any effect without proper deployment descriptors.  In any event I don't think the asadmin deploy would have access to your domain/lib or server/lib directory but rather only your application directory structure itself.

To do what you are trying to achieve, it sounds more like writing a simple ant script.